Laplace's demon and quantum mechanics paradox of not influencing our world?

We may regard the present state of the universe as the effect of its past and the cause of its future. An intellect which at a certain moment would know all forces that set nature in motion, and all positions of all items of which nature is composed, if this intellect were also vast enough to submit these data to analysis, it would embrace in a single formula the movements of the greatest bodies of the universe and those of the tiniest atom; for such an intellect nothing would be uncertain and the future just like the past could be present before its eyes.

This is the english translation of laplace's demon which is an idea that deals with the deterministic nature of the universe.
What we know is that classical mechanics is purely deterministic, so laplace's demon's powers must hold true due to his knowledge.
But laplace proposed this in early 18th century, and we have come a long way from there. We discovered the nature of objects in the universe which are not deterministic- particles. Quantum mechanics to a great extent is probabilistic and as such it must influence the nature of the universe, which it DOESN'T.
If all of the bricks in a house exhibit probabilistic nature then the house, through intuition, must also exhibit the same?
So how come these particles which behave in vividly probabilistic terms, when looked from afar become deterministic. When i see a small objects i cant define its nature, but when i see a bigger one made of the smaller objects; I CAN?
there has to be a size limit, a line, a line that says : Over this side is deterministic objects and over there is probabilistic.
But its all blurry and vague.
Why does quantum mechanics not influence classical mechanics?
and is the universe really deterministic?
"do not refer to chaos of the universe as the demon surpasses human ability of calculation, he can(as proposed) calculate anything"

If you flip a coin how confident are you of the result? What about if you flip 1 million coins?
